# How can I programmatically disable 'settings' option in android?

Tags: android

How can I **disable** ***settings*** option in android, I dont want user to get into it. I have launched home intent when settings process is running but its not seems to be good. Any other way to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "settings option?" Are you using your own PreferenceActivity, or do you mean the device's settings?

Comment: Are you writing an App, or are you an administrator trying to restrict company phones?

Comment: I mean settings option, I am writing an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most you can do is take advantage of Device Administration, introduced in 2.2, to enforce settings policies.  Details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)